# Integration Azure Active Directory SSO in our own asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We're developing an ASP.NET application for multiple customers and some of the customers want to login with their Azure Active Directory accounts using SSO. My question is: What is the best way to implement this and which azure technology should we use? Our asp.net application is aldo hosted in our own azure subscription but it doesn't use azure sql. At this moment it still uses Microsoft SQL Server. The conversion to azure sql is something we'll look into in the future. We also want to use the groups of these users (from our curstomers) to give the users certain rights within our application.

We've looked into Azure enterprise application, but the way I understand it, you'll need to make a new link for every customer. For example: www.customer1.mydomain.com / www.customer2.mydomain.com instead of using just the www.mydomain.com.

The expected result is that we have one website of our webapplication www.mydomain.com. When a customer of us goes to the site and uses their own azure actove directory account to login with SSO, they come into the account that's linked to their subscription and they only see the items that they should see depending on which azure active directory groups they're member of.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use Multi-tenant app. It is available to users in both their home tenant and other tenants.

For example, the Azure portal and Office portal are multi-tenant apps. Users from different tenants can use the same portal.

There is also a detailed tutorial for multi-tenant application pattern, you may refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Thank you for the information. I communicated this to our developing team and they'll look into this technology. I'll post an update when I have more information.

Comment: @NathanB May i know if you have any further concerns?